# Mostrar diferente información en PHP con mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Soy nueva estudiando PHP y estoy intentando que en la web se muestre algunas secciones de noticias que subirían los usuarios en la web, en la base de datos tengo lo siguiente en una carpeta llamada proyectos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a la hora del html no se como insertar estas noticias para que se muestren, si con la instrucción UPDATE .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACLARACIÓN

Las sentencias SQL

1. SELECT -> Mostrar información de la base de datos
2. UPDATE -> Modificar información existente de la base de datos
3. DELETE -> Eliminar fisicamente información de la base de datos
4. CREATE/INSERT -> Almacenar información en la base de datos

Una forma de hacerlo es con el dirver mysqli, es decir primero conectarte a tu base de datos, para ejecutar una consulta y obtener dichos resultados; como quieres tal vez obtener todos hacemos uso del método **mysqli_fetch_assoc**

```
<?php

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "noticias");

$consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM noticias");
$consulta->execute();

while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
    echo $fila["nombre"];
    echo $fila["info"];
    echo $fila["tecno"];
    echo $fila["tiempo"];
}
```

ACLARACIONES:

1. Puedes meter este código en un archivo siempre que sea extensión .php para que funcione la lógica de programación
2. Si por alguna razón deseas meter esto dentro de un archivo que tenga también HTML, necesitas primero que sea extensión .php pero también cerrar las etiquetas PHP para que el contenido no se mezcle con las etiquetas HTML

   ```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
       <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Document</title>
       </head>
       <body>
       <h1>Listado de noticias</h1>
       <?php
       $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "noticias");

       $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM noticias");
       $consulta->execute();

       while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
           echo $fila["nombre"];
           echo $fila["info"];
           echo $fila["tecno"];
           echo $fila["tiempo"];
       }?>
       </body>
       </html>
   ```

> Obviamente debes adaptar los valores de conexión a los que estan
>   configurados en tu propia computadora; además de recordar que los
>   archivos PHP si estas trabajando con XAMPP van dentro de la carpeta
>   htdocs en una carpeta nueva que tu hagas con el nombre de tu proyecto